# Google Analytics Cohort data doesn't make sense

Tags: mobile, google-analytics, statistics

I'm trying to understand my cohort data and something there doesn't make sense:

On day/week 0 I have sometimes less than 100% - how can that be logic ?
If I choose "all sessions" shouldn't it be 100% always in day/week 0 ?

Why isn't it 100% when I choose a segment ? What does it mean if I have 50% on week 0 for a specific segment - that the start group is 50% of what ?

Also, where can I find benchmarks for this data in order to understand where I'm at in the industry (Mobile app, Transportation or service)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programing related

Comment: If this isn't the place for this question there where is it ?!